# Email verification in Play! 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to implement an email verification mechanism in play after after the user has registered on my website.

I am trying to understand what is the best architecture, this is my guess:

- Define a special route for email validation
- When the user register generate a token and save it inside the cache with a token -> user mapping.
- Send an email containing an url which points to the route providing the token as a parameter
- In the special route controller, retrieve the user from the cache using the token, validate the email and store it in the database.

Is my approach right?Is there a better solution?

Comment: Sounds about right. But you shouldn't rely solely on the cache for persisting the token - store it in the database as well. Also, probably remove the token afterwards (and have it expire at some point in any case?).

Comment: How do you handle expiration ?

Comment: Store the current timestamp in database with the token when it is created, then check to see if it is too old when the validation routine is activated. (You could also run a job periodically to clean up any old tokens, if db space is of concern.)

Comment: FYI: Full stack authentication module is available for Play 2.0, yet. It allows to register new accounts with e-mail verification, password recovering, logging with 3-rd party services etc. Additionally includes roles and permissions by `Deadbolt 2`, is multilingual and fully customisable. See: http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are modules out there that provide this functionality for Play 2.x. You might want to take a look at [Secure Social](http://securesocial.ws), or [Play Authenticate](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/) (as mentioned in a comment to the question by @biesior).